# Creating array of objects from large json data set

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapreduce

I am building my first larger application with AngularJS and am having difficulty building an array of objects for graphing data. Currently, I am taking an excel file and creating JSON data with SheetJS. 
There are on the order of 40,000 entries stored in a variable "jsonData" in the format:

[image: Console Printout of JSON]

My end goal is to graph the "Close Amount" per month for every airline. My idea is the creation of an array of objects that will store the airline name, and an array of claims data (called airlineData). I am having difficulty with looping through jsonData to add the desired info into the array of objects based on an if statement to see if that airline name has been added already.

I have the code on github- https://github.com/mikebly/tsa-luggage-analysis

For simplicity, here is my entire loop through jsonData:

```
for(i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){

    var date = XLSX.SSF.parse_date_code(jsonData[i]["Incident Date"],{date1904:false});
    var month = date.m; // Returns 1,2,3,...,12
    var airport = String(jsonData[i]["Airport Code"]);
    var airline = String(jsonData[i]["Airline Name"]);
    var claim = Number(jsonData[i]["Close Amount"]);
    claim = claim || 0; // Convert "-" to 0 for summing and average
    claimTotal += claim;

    // Build airport data array of objects to keep track of each airline's individual claims
    if(airlineData.includes(airline) == false){
      airlineData.name = airline;
      airlineData.claimTotal = claim;
    } else{
      continue;
    }

    // Build airline name array for dropdown box
    if (airlineNames.includes(airline) === false){
      airlineNames.push(airline);
    } else{
        continue;
    }

    // Build airport code array for dropdown box
    if (airportCodes.includes(airport) === false){
      airportCodes.push(airport);
    } else{
        continue;
    }

  }; // End loop through rows
```

My desired result would look something like:

```
 [{name:" ",claims:[]},
  {name:" ",claims:[]},
  {},
  //...
 ]
```

so I can select the desired dataset based on the name selected through a dropdown box.

Comment: Please post a sample json.

Comment: I included a link to a picture of a console.log of an sample entry. But it looks like the following-
{
Airline Name:"American Airlines  "
Airport Code:"ORD"
Airport Name:"Chicago O'Hare International Airport"
Claim Number:2010030168888
Claim Site:"Checked Baggage"
Claim Type:"Passenger Property Loss"
Close Amount:0
Date Received:40231
Disposition:"Deny"
Incident Date:40182.25
Item Category:"Personal Electronics; Travel Accessories"}

Comment: Please can you post that same json. And a sample output.

Comment: Claim is also a array of objects? if yes than what fields are included in it.

Comment: Claims should be just an array of 12 numbers, representing the total claims for a particular month. I was planning on using the month variable to set which index of the array to add the number into.

Comment: Please post a sample out. as it would be easier to help you out.

Comment: Currently airlineData just outputs [name: "undefined", claimTotal: 0] with a length of 0.

airlineNames and airportCodes output is fine, as they are just a simple array of strings.

Comment: do just want airline data as {name  : airline_name, claimTotal :  totalClaim, claims ; []}

Comment: Besides the claimTotal, yes. I am looking to go through the jsonData object by object, and add the claim info to my constructed airlineData array to the correct entry based on the airline name value.

Comment: updated my answer to handle multiple years

Comment: How is your project going? I don't see any updates on the gitub repo.

Answer (score 1):

I got the excel file and not sure if this is what you would like, average and sum per month is an object with keys of month-year.

```js
const dataPromise = fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amsterdamharu/amsterdamharu.github.io/master/data.txt")
.then(response=>response.text())
.then(
  text=>{
    const all = text.split("\n").map(row=>row.trim());
    const fields = all[0].split("\t").map(f=>f.trim());
    const info = all.slice(1).map(
      row=>row.split("\t").map(item=>item.trim())
    );
    return info.map(
      (row)=>
        row.reduce(
          (result,field,index)=>{
            result[fields[index]]=field;
            return result;
          },
          {}
        )
    );
  }
);
dataPromise.then(
  data=>{
    const raw =  data.reduce(
      (result,item)=>{
        const name = item["Airline Name"];
        const claims = (result[name] = (result[name] || {}));
        const date = new Date(item["Incident Date"]);
        const month = date.getMonth()+1;
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const claim = Number(item["Close Amount"].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));
        if(isNaN(claim)){
          debugger;
        }
        claims[`${month}-${year}`]=claims[`${month}-${year}`]||[];
        claims[`${month}-${year}`].push(claim);
        return result;
      },
      {}
    );
    console.log("raw object:",raw);
    const objectAveragePerMonth = Object.keys(raw).map(
      name=>({
          name,
          monthAverage:Object.entries(raw[name]).reduce(
            (result,[key,values])=>{
              const noZeros = values.filter(m=>m);//remove zero values
              result[key] = (noZeros.length)
                ? noZeros.reduce((sum,item)=>sum+item,0)/noZeros.length
                : 0;
              return result;
            },
            {}
          )
      })
    );
    console.log("average per month:",objectAveragePerMonth);
    const objectSumPerMonth = Object.keys(raw).map(
      name=>({
        name,
        totalPerMonth:Object.entries(raw[name]).reduce(
          (result,[key,values])=>{
            result[key] = values.reduce((sum,item)=>sum+item,0);
            return result;
          },
          {}
        )
      })
    );
    console.log("sum per month",objectSumPerMonth);
    const objectTotal = Object.keys(raw).map(
      name=>({
        name,
        total:Object.entries(raw[name]).reduce(
          (result,[key,values])=>result+values.reduce((sum,item)=>sum+item,0),
          0
        )
      })
    );
    console.log("total per airline",objectTotal);
  }
);
```

You could look at [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to understand the code more.

Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I am going to have to read through those to better understand how everything is working. To start off though, I am a little confused about the start of your code, with you info const and then being mapped to data. Was this all because you copied stuff in directly from the excel file?

Comment: @MikeBlydenburgh Yes, I ran this in the browser so just copy the the first column in fields and the data in info. Then use field and info to create data which is an array of each row of info with the names used in fields. [Here](https://amsterdamharu.github.io/claims.html) is an online version with all the data from the excel file.

Comment: Does makes my JSON output useless and I have to play around with some manual data selection with SheetJS? I tried to use my array of objects, jsonData, for the info and it didn't quite work. There are 41,000 rows of data for this file, manually copying all of the information will make this file rather large to scroll through, and there are multiple separate excel files for more years. After I got this working for this single file I was planning on having a file input so the you can select any claims year file. Am I misunderstanding how you're getting the data in there to begin with?

Comment: @MikeBlydenburgh I updated the answer to load the data from a tab delimited version of your excel file located [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amsterdamharu/amsterdamharu.github.io/master/data.txt) you can run the code in the answer but it may take a while because it's lots of data and Stack Overflow will print out the console.logs quite slow. If you're using node you can just load a tab delimited file using the file API in node.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
// Code goes here

var jsonData = [{
  "Airline Name":"American Airlines ",
  "Airport Code":"ORD",
  "Airport Name":"Chicago O'Hare International Airport",
  "Claim Number":2010030168888,
  "Claim Site":"Checked Baggage",
  "Claim Type":"Passenger Property Loss",
  "Close Amount":0,
  "Date Received":40231,
  "Disposition":"Deny",
  "Incident Date":40182.25,
  "Item Category":"Personal Electronics; Travel Accessories"
}];
var map = {};
jsonData.forEach(function(obj){
  if(!map[obj["Airline Name"]])
    map[obj["Airline Name"]] = {};
  map[obj["Airline Name"]].name = obj["Airline Name"];
  map[obj["Airline Name"]].claims = map[obj["Airline Name"]].claims || [];
  map[obj["Airline Name"]].claims.push(obj["Claim Number"]);
  map[obj["Airline Name"]].claimTotal = map[obj["Airline Name"]].claimTotal !== undefined ? map[obj["Airline Name"]].claimTotal + obj["Close Amount"] : 0; 
});
var arr = Object.values(map);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is correctly making an array of 180 objects, for each airline. Each object is counting the number of claims correctly, after comparing the output of a sample to looking at the excel file. It is not, however, summing the Close Amount for each object correctly, it just spits out 0 for every object's .claimTotal. On a side note, I have not seen a technique like this before, thank you for showing me this.

Comment: @MikeBlydenburgh i have updated the snipet, it will calculate close amount correctly now.

Comment: There appears to be some weird parsing going on still, for a random airline chosen:

claimTotal= "1579.4-00157500000000-303.850009000-0000--0037.50000-049000001240-0000000001200-000-000729.950-230.510461.1080.07000050000000000--0-500-049.9542"...and it goes on and on. 

It is reading the numbers somewhat, as the first two entries are $0, followed by $1579.40, followed by some more $0, and then $1575.